# Foundation 5: Dropdown menu links not activating

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I've found this similar error mentioned since Foundation 3, usually because foundation.min.js was not included. I have this included but links in the dropdown menu are not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" />
<script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">

    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">dashboard</a></h1>
        </li>
         <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="chapters.php">chapters</a></li>
        <li><a href="sections.php">sections</a></li>
        <li><a href="paragraphs.php">paragraphs</a></li>
        <li><a href="references.php">references</a></li>
        <li><a href="annotations.php">annotations</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.php">help</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="name">Create</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="categories.php?task=new">new chapter</a></li>
                <li><a href="sections.php?task=new">new section</a></li>
                <li><a href="paragraphs.php?task=new">new paragraph</a></li>
                <li><a href="annotations.php?task=new">new annotation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing a setting? I've seen preventDefault() mentioned as a possible culprit, but why on earth would the default click behavior be prevented...for clickable menu links?

Comment: Looks like its working to me http://jsfiddle.net/u3m1n4go/

Comment: Bizarre. I don't understand why it's not working on my server. In the small view, the hamburger menu doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).foundation();` line must be invoked before the closing BODY tag, not HEAD tag. I was loading foundation before the DOM elements had loaded.

This explains the whacky behavior.